# The center is still cold when I deep fry my precooked frozen chicken

Tags: freezing, deep-frying, defrosting, thawing

Two days ago, after I seasoned my chicken breasts I stuffed them with smoked turkey slices (not a fan of ham) and some mozzarella cheese (don't have swiss). I battered them with flour, seasoned egg, and bread crumbs. I also made another batch with panko. I baked them in the oven for 35 minutes. Then, I put them in the freezer after I left them to cool.

Today I wanted to fry them. The batter was almost gonna burn, I even tried to start frying with less heat but the chicken and filling was still very cold in the center. This recipe was successful when I fried the chicken right away without freezing before. What can I do to defrost fast without having to leave it in the fridge over night? Is there a way to cook the chicken thoroughly in the fryer?

And I have the same question for home made burger patties. How can I thaw big batches fast? Putting them in water seems inconvenient for me as I like to season my meat when forming it rather than on the fryer. I sometimes also fill with cheese in the middle (the kids like the surprise!).

Comment: Why are you freezing in between? To speed up cooking? Accounting for defrost time, I can't imagine you are saving any time.

Comment: Also, are you frying the burgers? You can throw frozen burgers on the grill/pan. I wouldn't deep fry a burger?

Comment: Im freezing because i want to serve it later.. days later :)

Comment: And no im not deep frying the burgers i pan fry yhem. but as i said when i fill them with cheese and the filling wouldnt melt.

Comment: Isn't deep frying it the second day, just as much work as baking it from scratch?

Comment: You have to defrost the meat, but you've ruled out the normal defrost techniques (fridge overnight and water), which basically just leaves the microwave as a defrost technique (but you might end up cooking the food in the microwave rather than just defrosting it). The sane solution is to just put the food in the fridge overnight.

Comment: Freeze them in their raw form.

Comment: Why are you deep frying precooked chicken?   Why not just pull it from the freezer to fridge a few hours before?

Answer (score 1):

Cooking meat while it's a little frozen generally works fine with methods that have some wiggle room in how much extra time you can add. Unfortunately this isn't the case with frying, and even if you cut the meat into small pieces I don't think you'd have much success.

My favorite method to quickly thaw meat is using a microwave. Most microwaves have a thaw setting, and it's often based on the weight you select. Typically microwave thawing is just done on a very low power, but you need to be very careful and frequently check/turn the meat or it may start to cook. [This page](http://www.epicurious.com/expert-advice/how-to-defrost-any-meat-article) has a really useful guide on thawing methods.